# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport)

Tags: c++

I define this in dll compile process.

```
# if defined(BUILD_DLL)
# define COMMON_API __declspec(dllexport)
# else
# define COMMON_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

and:

```
template <typename T> class COMMON_API Singleton {
public:
static T& GetInstance()
{
    static T s_instance;
    return s_instance;
};
    ***
};
```

and:

```
class COMMON_API CRegExecThreadPool:public Singleton<CRegExecThreadPool>
{
  friend class Singleton<CRegExecThreadPool>;
  ***
}
```

then I try use it in exe:

```
Commonlib::CRegExecThreadPool::GetInstance();
```

but got the link error,I don't understand why. what can I do?

"__declspec(dllimport) public: static class Commonlib::CRegExecThreadPool & __cdecl Commonlib::Singleton::GetInstance(void)"

> error LNK2019: 无法解析的外部符号 "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class Commonlib::CRegExecThreadPool & __cdecl Commonlib::Singleton::GetInstance(void)" (_*imp*?GetInstance@?$Singleton@VCRegExecThreadPool@Commonlib@@@Commonlib@@SAAEAVCRegExecThreadPool@2@XZ)

Comment: you can't export template from dll. `template` is only compile time entity (it is only a recipe). Only instances of template become part of final code.  You can export from dll template instantiation for some specific types.

Comment: yes, thank you. you are right!